# Equivalence between Sobolev norm and Sobolev-Slobodeckij norm for $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ when $s$ is an integer

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Take $W^{1,2} = H^1$ for example. If we still use Slobodeckij norm (which is normally defined for a fractional Sobolev space) as follows for a $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ with the exponent being in integer:
$$
[u]_{1,\Omega}^2:= \int_{\Omega} \int_{\Omega} \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2}} \,dxdy.
$$
Is this equivalent to the Sobolev semi-norm:
$$
|u|_{1,\Omega}^2:= \int_{\Omega} |Du|^2 dx\,?
$$

My guess is no because, when we divide $\overline{\Omega} = \overline{\Omega}_1 \cup \overline{\Omega}_2$ into two non-overlapping subdomain, for the Sobolev semi-norm it is just adding broken norms on the subdomains:
$$
|u|_{1,\Omega}^2 = |u|_{1,\Omega_1}^2 + |u|_{1,\Omega_2}^2.
$$
However for the Slobodeckij norm, it has some cross term like:
$$
\int_{\Omega_1} \int_{\Omega_2} \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2}} \,dxdy,
$$
and apparently,
$$
[u]_{1,\Omega}^2 \neq [u]_{1,\Omega_1}^2 + [u]_{1,\Omega_2}^2.
$$

I am guessing the equivalence relies on the regularities of the $\Omega$, but I could not find any reference on this. Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct behavior of fractional norms in the limit $s \to 1^-$ is$$\lim_{s \to 1^-} (1 - s)[u]_{s, p}^p = K(p, N)\|\nabla u\|_p^p,$$where $K(p, N)$ is a constant depending on $p$ and $N$, as shown in a paper by Bourgain, Brezis, and Mironescu [here](http://hal.upmc.fr/file/index/docid/747692/filename/another_look_sobolev_spaces_2000.pdf).

> J. Bourgain, H. Brezis, P. Mironescu. *Another look at Sobolev spaces*, in: J.L. Menaldi, E. Rofman, A. Sulem (Eds.), Optimal Control and Partial Differential Equations, A Volume in Honour of A. Bensoussan's 60th Birthday, IOS Press, 2001, pp. 439-455.

If $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are disjoint, it means that $|x - y| \ge d > 0$ when $x \in \Omega_1$ and $y \in \Omega_2$, therefore the cross term will tend to zero.